# Highcharts rangeselector navigation - start on the lowest date / value

Tags: highcharts, highcharts-gantt

On this official Highcharts demo https://www.highcharts.com/demo/gantt/with-navigation
the display starts at the end
[image]

What do I need to change, so the navigation range starts at the beginning like so?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `setExtremes` method in `load` event:

```
    chart: {
        events: {
            load: function() {
                const xAxis = this.xAxis[0];
                xAxis.setExtremes(xAxis.dataMin, xAxis.dataMin + xAxis.max - xAxis.min);
            }
        }
    }
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/8tk52zdw/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis#setExtremes